# Targets for opening JSF page on same tab and different tab

Tags: javascript, html, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a menu bar with following structure. The requirement is, on clicking the first three links, new page content should be displayed on same window where as the fourth link click should lead to new tab. But all the links works the same way now. The content is getting displayed on new tab.

```
<ul class="menu">
            <li><h:commandLink id="link1" target="main">  </h:commandLink></li>

            <li><h:commandLink id="link2" target="main"> </h:commandLink></li>

            <li><h:commandLink id="link3" target="main"> </h:commandLink></li>                    

            <li><h:commandLink id="link4" target="_new"> </h:commandLink></li>
        </ul>
```

Could someone suggest that what should be target for first 3 links to prevent opening new tab?

Comment: What exactly did you thought `target="main"` does?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only want a simple link you should use `<h:outputLink>` tag. Whatever, `target` attribute

> Specifies the name of the HTML **`<frame>`** that should display the
>   contents of the URL specified in the `href` attribute.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <h:outputLink value="http://google.com">
            <f:verbatim >This will appear as a Link to Google.</f:verbatim>
        </h:outputLink>
    </li>              
    <li>
        <h:outputLink value="http://google.com" target="_blank">
            <f:verbatim >This will appear as a Link to Google to a NEW tab.</f:verbatim>
        </h:outputLink>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with JSF much, however I am sure `target` attribute will work in the same way with HTML and JSF.

```
<link target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">
```

- **_blank**: Load in a new window
- **_self**: Load in the same frame as it was clicked
- **_parent**: Load in the parent frameset
- **_top**: Load in the full body of the window
- **framename** Load in a named frame